# Nginx 502 (Bad Gateway) error when accessing to api server in elastic beanstalk

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed my products on `elastic-beanstalk`.
When accessing to api server, `502 Bad Gateway` is returned.

Here is the stack.

```
・client: react/axios
・api: golang/gin
・web server: nginx
・db: mysql
・container: docker
・ci-tool: travis
・deploy: aws elastic beanstalk
```

Entire source code is here:
https://github.com/jpskgc/article

In my local docker environment, there is no problem to request to api server.
But in elastic beanstalk environment, it returns `502 Bad Gateway`

Here is the actual url.
http://multidocker-env.vwnrixavuv.ap-northeast-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this error in server log.

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/containers/server-e34065c90525-stdouterr.log
-------------------------------------
/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64/link: signal: killed
```

This is caused by memory shortage.
So I fix to volume up memory for api from `128` to `512` in `Dockerrun.aws.json`.

```
    {
      "name": "server",
      "image": "jpskgc/multi-api",
      "hostname": "api",
      "essential": false,
      "memory": 512
    },
```